# can I upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 14.10 by sudo do-release-upgrade?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 14.10

I'm looking for answers to any Ubuntu version can upgrade with no errors, problems.

I'm using 14.04 LTS x64 desktop edition with all repos (included 3rd party) up to date.

I just enter a command

`$ sudo do-release-upgrade`

Previous versions was unable to do upgrade.

Any one has tried to do this upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10.

You can always upgrade any version to the next version with do-release-upgrade.

For an LTS release, you have the choice to either upgrade to the immediate next version or the next LTS version (when it's released).

Note that do-release-upgrade doesn't require `sudo`, interestingly enough, because it makes its own calls to `sudo` during its run.

Comment: I did not notice till read from here that sudo is not required. Thnx for that.

Comment: BTW When I tried any previous versions, always get some errors. But now looks like no errors during, after upgrade.

Comment: You have to choose to upgrade to any new versions when upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04. It could not jump directly from previous LTS to the newest LTS.